# Google Places API Search, Instead of 20 Results can I get lower than 20 so 10 etc?

Tags: api

So i'm currently loading in the places from the google places API, and obtaining the 20 results with the next page token. However is it possible to obtain say 10 results instead of 20?

Thanks!